# while loop in procedure sybase

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

In oracle when we write a procedure we do it like this :

> COUNT_START:= LL_COUNT; 
>   WHILE LL_COUNT > 0 LOOP 
>        IF LL_COUNT > 20 THEN 
>         COUNT_START := 20; 
>           ELSE 
>        COUNT_START := LL_COUNT; 
>        LL_COUNT := 0; 
>       END IF;

I am writing a procedure in sybase :

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE P_RDS_EOD_ARCH_PURGE
  v_test numeric(10,0)

 AS

 BEGIN

 DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(200)
 DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(200)
 DECLARE @TYPE VARCHAR(200)
 DECLARE @SQL_TXT VARCHAR(255)


 SELECT @ID   = '1' 
 SELECT @NAME = 'P_TEST'
 SELECT @TYPE = 'SELECT'

 SELECT @SQL_TXT ='RANDOM QUERY'

 EXECUTE @ID, @NAME , @TYPE, @SQL_TXT
```

After I execute my query I want to do a **LOOP** and to assign values, how to do that in sybase

Comment: It's usually helpful to put more than just the 'sybase' tag on a question.  Since you are working with Sybase ASE, and asking questions about T-SQL, you should add those tags.  Better tagging will help you get faster/better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops are pretty basic in TSQL:

```
while boolean_expression 
  statement
```

If your statement is more than 1 line, then you can enclose it in begin/end statements;

```
while aStatementIsTrue
begin 
   update myTable
   set myCol = "whatever"

   select someOtherThing
end
```

More details can be found in the [Sybase T-SQL User's Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/X97649.htm).